# Flutter custom AppBar on one page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing **Flutter** application with `AppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar`. Here is the code:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;

  MainPage(this.model);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MainPageState();
  }
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _openSelectedPage() {
    switch(_selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return HomePage(widget.model);
      case 1:
        return CapturePage(widget.model);
      case 2:
        return MealsPage(widget.model);
      default:
        return HomePage(widget.model);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: _openSelectedPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            title: Text('Capture'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
            title: Text('Meals'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I have custom `AppBar` on `MealsPage`? If I add another `Scaffold` in `build` method of `MealsPage`, then it creates two `AppBar`s, which is not what I want. I only want to have one `AppBar`, the one that I define in `MealsPage`.

Comment: if you add some images of what you want to achieve, we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;

  MainPage(this.model);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MainPageState();
  }
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _openSelectedPage() {
    switch (_selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return HomePage(widget.model);
      case 1:
        return CapturePage(widget.model);
      case 2:
        return MealsPage(widget.model);
      default:
        return HomePage(widget.model);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _selectedIndex == 2 ? null : AppBar(title: Text('My App')), 
      body: _openSelectedPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            title: Text('Capture'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
            title: Text('Meals'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```